# Script that checks and saves text to file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Can you give example for a script where user is asked to enter name, surname and age. And then   check if name and surname contains only letters and age contains only digits? And if the information is correct it is added to file.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Needless to say.. it is not.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say that it's "needless to say" since it certainly smells like it could be homework.

Comment: Can you be sure, that a name like "O'Reilly" has to be excluded, "Mc Intosh", "Müller-Smørebrød"?

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like homework, so nobody should write the script for you.

Instead, I would suggest learning how to use these two commands:

- [read](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html)
- [grep](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_02.html)

Comment: also will be usefull information about tests (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tests.html ) in bash.

Answer (score 1):

Use `echo` to display a message, and the `read` to read a line of input. These are shell builtins, so consult your shell's manual for more information.

```
echo "What is your name?"
read -r name
echo "What is your age?"
read -r age
```

To validate the age, check whether it contains characters other than a digit. The only portable built-in shell construct that allows this is `case` (some shells have extensions for regexp matching).

```
case $age in
  *[!0-9]*) echo 1>&2 "Your age must consist of digits only."; exit 2;;
esac
```

To validate the name, check whether it contains non-printable characters. (Note that [names can contain pretty much arbitrary characters](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/); also, not everybody has a “surname”: treat a name as an arbitrary string.)

```
case $name in
  *[![:print:]]*) echo 1>&2 "Your name must consist of printable characters only."; exit 2;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not homework I would suggest looking into using PERL or Python and simply have the PERL read like this:

```
$name = <STDIN>;
chomp $name;
($forename, $surname) = split(<regex>, $name);
if($surname =~ /<regex>/) execute something
```

Python would be similar so to continue just look at [PERL regex](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).  Script is not exact but you get the idea.